# Discover private DNS of load balancers in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-cloudformation

This is a pretty common issue but I am having trouble finding a proper answer to how to go about this.

I have two apps, which will run on EC2s. These apps will be in their separate autoscaling groups, which are behind their own ELBs. 
These 2 apps need to talk to each other, so they need to know the internal DNS of the ELBs.

I can think of few ways to go about this:

1. Create the ELBs before-hand and use them by their name in the CF template. (I  have not tried this, there was a post about not being able to reference an externally created ELB name in the CF template. But I'm guessing it should be doable).
2. Create the ELBs first in the CF, and then get their private IPs through `Fn::Gett` (or something similar), and then write this value to an environmental variable in the app.
3. Implement a service discovery, where each app/ELB, write its private IP to a DB or something similar so other apps and discover the IPs of the other services/apps.

Option #2 would be the best case, and I'm assuming this is the process that is most infra-as-a-code. However, I cannot find proper documentation on how to do it.

If anyone can refer me the right way of going about this, I very much appreciate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ELB has an **AWS-assigned DNS name** that you should use.

[image: ELB DNS name]

If you create the ELB through CloudFormation you can get the name with `Fn:GetAtt ELB.DNSName` as described in [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer Return Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#aws-properties-ec2-elb-return-values):

```
[...]
  MyELB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      ...

Outputs:
  ELBName:
    Value: !GetAtt MyELB.DNSName            <<< Like this
```

BTW *Never ever* refer directly to the resolved IP addresses anywhere because they change often, for example when the ELB scales up, down, goes through maintenance, etc.

Hope that helps :)